# get count of words in column sql

Tags: sql, oracle, word-count

after the following queries

```
SELECT * FROM table;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(description || '!', '[^[:punct:]]') 
    FROM table;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ( description, '[' ||  REGEXP_REPLACE ( description || '!', '[^[:punct:]]')  || ']') test 
    FROM table;

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(UPPER(TEST), ' ', '#') test 
    FROM (SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (description, '[' ||  REGEXP_REPLACE (description || '!', '[^[:punct:]]')  || ']') test 
    FROM table);
```

I have a column in an oracle sql looking like:

```
TEST
 ---------------------------------------------
 SPOKE#WITH#MR#SMITHS#ASSISTANT
 EMAILED#FOR#VISIT
 SCHEDULING#OFFICE#LM#FOR#VISIT
 LM#FOR#VISIT
 LM#FOR#VISIT
 PHONE#CALL
 ---------------------------------------------
```

all of the words are separated by #'s.  I would like to get counts of the occurrences of words, for example:

```
word | count
------------
LM   |  3
FOR  |  4
VISIT|  4
PHONE|  1
```

etc etc.  I'm new to oracle sql and am only familiar with rudimentary mysql commands.  any help or pointers to tutorials would also be helpful.  thank you.

edit: there are approximately 1500 rows with about 250 unique responses that i'm trying to account for

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Update your question with the code that you've attempted.

Comment: @Ted So, there can be duplicate values for TEST, like LM#FOR#VISIT in the example data? You have mentioned that there will be "about 250 unique responses".

Comment: @JosephB Yes, correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH mydata AS
  ( SELECT 'SPOKE#WITH#MR#SMITHS#ASSISTANT' AS str FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'EMAILED#FOR#VISIT' FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'SCHEDULING#OFFICE#LM#FOR#VISIT' FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LM#FOR#VISIT' FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'LM#FOR#VISIT' FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PHONE#CALL' FROM dual
  ),
  splitted_words AS
  (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'[^#]+', 1, level) AS word
    FROM mydata
      CONNECT BY level   <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(str,'[^#]')) + 1
    AND PRIOR str         = str
    AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT word,
      COUNT(1)
FROM splitted_words
GROUP BY word;
```

If your table is `YOUR_TABLE` and column is `YOUR_COLUMN`

```
  WITH splitted_words AS
  (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COLUMN,'[^#]+', 1, level) AS word
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
      CONNECT BY level   <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(YOUR_COLUMN,'[^#]')) + 1
    AND PRIOR YOUR_COLUMN         = YOUR_COLUMN
    AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT word,
      COUNT(1)
FROM splitted_words
GROUP BY word;
```

Comment: thanks for your response... but the column is approximately 1500 rows with probably over 250 unique responses... how would i account for all the responses?

Comment: @Ted You simply select directly from the table. WITH splitted_words AS
  (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(test,'[^#]+', 1, level) AS word
    FROM <<tablename>>
      CONNECT BY level   <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(test,'[^#]')) + 1
    AND PRIOR test         = test
    AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT word,
      COUNT(1)
FROM splitted_words
GROUP BY word;

Comment: @JosephB I can't seem to figure out why, but I'm getting the error `"TEST": invalid identifier`

Comment: @Ted `mydata` in my query is just a view to show some sample data.. In your case, you can skip it.. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: @OracleUser still getting the same error... here is what my query looks like (substituting YOUR_TABLE for my table and YOUR_COLUMN as TEST):
'WITH splitted_words AS
  (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEST,'[^#]+', 1, level) AS word
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
      CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(regexp_replace(TEST,'[^#]')) + 1
    AND PRIOR TEST = TEST
    AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT word,
      COUNT(1)
FROM splitted_words
GROUP BY word;'

Comment: Can you please join in chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50408/maheshs-room)

Comment: @Ted It appears that TEST is not a column in YOUR_TABLE. Could you please run SELECT TEST FROM YOUR_TABLE; to verify it?

Comment: @JosephB correct, TEST is not a column in my table, but i ran a few queries before to make a column called TEST. they are at the top of my original post